# Text Classification for Python- Nonetype Error

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining, text-classification, corpus

I am working on a basic project with Python regarding Text Classification.
I am using nltk, and I have imported its Brown Corpus.
While trying to classify one group as "positive" and the other group as "negative", I am getting a nonetype error.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
brown.fileids()

categories = brown.categories()
categories

news_text = brown.sents(categories='news')
editorial_text= brown.sents(categories='editorial')
romance_text= brown.sents(categories='romance')
target_text=news_text + editorial_text

total_text=news_text + editorial_text + romance_text

data=[]

for text in total_text:
    if text in target_text:
        label= "pos"
    else:
        label = "neg"

data.extend( [(label, text) for text in total_text] )
```

Below is the error message that I am getting:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f8709bb455fe> in <module>()
      1 data=[]
      2 
----> 3 for text in total_text:
      4     if text in target_text:
      5         label= "pos"

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/collections.py in iterate_from(self, start_index)
    330                         'inconsistent list value (num elts)')
    331 
--> 332             for value in sublist[max(0, start_index-index):]:
    333                 yield value
    334 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/collections.py in iterate_from(self, start_index)
    330                         'inconsistent list value (num elts)')
    331 
--> 332             for value in sublist[max(0, start_index-index):]:
    333                 yield value
    334 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py in iterate_from(self, start_tok)
    400 
    401             # Get everything we can from this piece.
--> 402             for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok-offset)):
    403                 yield tok
    404 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py in iterate_from(self, start_tok)
    291         while filepos < self._eofpos:
    292             # Read the next block.
--> 293             self._stream.seek(filepos)
    294             self._current_toknum = toknum
    295             self._current_blocknum = block_index

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Yes. Log what "total_text" is to see more what's going on

Comment: Why is `piece.stream` None

Comment: Your iteration code ought to work; it does for me, in fact. Have you tested that the code you pasted in your question _really_ triggers the error? (The line numbers in the code and in the error trace don't match, so this is clearly not the exact code you were using; but perhaps it is equivalent.) And are you able to read sentences from the `brown` corpus using simpler code? (I.e., have you downloaded the Brown corpus?)